# Real Analysis: Integrable

Tags: real-analysis

I need help with part (b) of this problem.

Suppose that $f : [a, b] → R$ is integrable.

(a) Prove that if one value of $f(x)$ is changed at some point $x ∈ [a,b]$, then $f$ is still integrable and integrates to the same value as before.

(b) Prove that the observation in part (a) holds if a finite number of values of $f$ are changed.

[image: Solution For (a)]

[image: Solution for (b)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply induction. Change the value at one point at a time till you go from one function to the other.

Comment: I've posted my solution for part (b). Can you please check if it's correct?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what my answer says.